# NASM/DOS - Use value from array of int and add it to a pointer

Tags: assembly, hex, nasm, dos

I'm learning assembly (FreeDOS, 16 bits) and I have an issue.

I'm trying to print a char value (to print an hexadecimal) using an array.
The idea is to do something like this:

```
mov bp, hexnum ; Get address of hexanum
add bp, [tab + 1] ; Add 2 to bs pointer
mov dl, [bp] ; to print '2' from hexnum
mov ah, 2
int 0x21

tab:
db 1,2,6,7 ; indexes of value to print

hexnum:
db '0','1','2' ; etc.
```

However, if I replace second line by

```
add bp, 2
```

then it works.

I guess I'm doing something wrong because it should print '2' but it doesn't. I couldn't find what's wrong. Can someone give me a hint ?

EDIT:

Well, I managed to solve it by myself. Here is what it looks like:

```
mov bx, hexnum ; Get address of hexanum
add bl, [tab + 1] ; Add 2 to bs pointer
mov dl, [bx] ; to print '2' from hexnum
mov ah, 2
int 0x21

tab:
db 1,2,6,7 ; indexes of value to print

hexnum:
db '0','1','2' ; etc.
```

I guess it's because `bx` is **16** bits while `[tab + 1]` is **8** bits. So I had to add to `bl` instead of `bx`.

Comment: `mov bs, hexnum ; Get address of hexanum`. There is no register named `bs` and two memory operands would not be allowed. So what is `bs` supposed to mean?

Comment: I used bp not bs indeed, I'm editing it

Comment: Don't edit "[resolved]" into your question title.  Post an answer to your own question.  Or if it's unlikely to help anyone else, you can delete your question if there weren't already any helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not resolved, yet!

The solution that you found yourself (adding the byte from the *tab* list to the `BL` register) **only** works because in this little program all of the addresses fall within the same 256 bytes memory page. In an other program it could fail since you don't pick up the carry from the byte addition.

### Solution 1 picks up the carry (`ADC`)

```
 mov bx, hexnum
 add bl, [tab + 1] ; Add 2 to bx pointer
 ADC bh, 0         ;
 mov dl, [bx]
 mov ah, 02h
 int 21h
 ...
tab:
 db  1,2,6,7       ; indexes of value to print
hexnum:
 db  '0','1','2'   ; etc.
```

### Solution 2 defines the offsets as words (`DW`)

```
 mov bx, hexnum
 add bx, [tab + 2] ; Add 2 to bx pointer
 mov dl, [bx]
 mov ah, 02h
 int 21h
 ...
tab:
 DW  1,2,6,7       ; indexes of value to print
hexnum:
 db  '0','1','2'   ; etc.
```

Comment: Or use zero-extend the table value: `movzx bx, byte [tab + 1]` / `add bx, hexnum`.  (Or better, `mov dl, [hexnum+bx]`).  For compat with 286 and earlier: `xor bx,bx` / `mov bl, [tab+1]` instead of movzx.  If you were adding to another register value instead of an immediate, you'd need a scratch register to do a zero-extending load into.